# TypeScript Errors in Vue 3 mono repo codebase

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue, npm-workspaces

I have recently updated a codebase using Vue 3 (CLI/Webpack) + PrimeVue to a monorepo using npm workspaces and I have since TS errors with the PrimeVue components like so:

```
JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.

'__VLS_58' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'InputText' is not a valid JSX element.
```

My repo has the following structure:

```
- apps
-- api
-- ui        <--- Vue 3 code base
--- src
--- dist
--- node_modules
--- tsconfig.json
- node_modules
- tsconfig.base.json
```

My tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends": "./../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env", "jest"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

My tsconfig.base.json:

```json
{
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "rootDirs": ["apps/**/**/*.ts", "apps/**/**/*.tsx", "apps/**/**/*.vue"],
  "include": ["./apps/b2b/**/*.ts", "./apps/b2b/**/*.tsx", "./apps/**/**/*.vue"]
}
```

My root package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "./apps/*"
  ]
}
```

And as an example the InputText.d.ts (one of the components that errors):

```
import { InputHTMLAttributes } from 'vue';
import { ClassComponent, GlobalComponentConstructor } from '../ts-helpers';

export interface InputTextProps extends InputHTMLAttributes {
    /**
     * Value of the component.
     */
    modelValue?: string | undefined;
}

export interface InputTextSlots {
}

export declare type InputTextEmits = {
    /**
     * Emitted when the value changes.
     * @param {string} value - New value.
     */
    'update:modelValue': (value: string | undefined) => void;
}

declare class InputText extends ClassComponent<InputTextProps, InputTextSlots, InputTextEmits> { }

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
    interface GlobalComponents {
        InputText: GlobalComponentConstructor<InputText>
    }
}

/**
 *
 * InputText renders a text field to enter data.
 *
 * Demos:
 *
 * - [InputText](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/inputtext)
 *
 */
export default InputText;
```

I can't figure out which dependency seems to be broken nor how to make TS happy again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is not a config error linked to the code base but a Volar VS Code extension problem that started pretty much at the same time as the refactoring: https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/discussions/592.

Haven't solved it yet as I just found out what that was actually about.